# SQL Server CDC: How does __$seqval work under the covers?

Tags: sql-server, cdc

Regarding the `__$seqval` values, we make the following assumptions:

1. count of unique `__$seqval` values in a CDC table will equal the
   count of rows.
2. ordering a select from a CDC table by `__$seqval` will accurately
   reproduce order of both transactions and operations within
   transactions as they appear in the CDC table.

Are these assumptions true, or can you only order CDC data by including both start LSN *and* seqval?

Thank you and regards!

Answer (score 3):

For #1, I'm not sure, but I wouldn't make that assumption. I have seen duplicate sequence values across tables, in related transactions with slightly different start LSNs. I've never noticed duplicates within the same table, but that doesn't mean it can't happen.

Regarding your overall expectation, use the combination of all four [sequence values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-capture-instance-ct-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) to produce a deterministic list of the transactions and the operations within them. I tend to use:

`ORDER BY __$start_lsn ASC, __$seqval ASC, __$command_id ASC, __$operation ASC`

For a more official order, here's the clustered index definition on my servers for each CDC table, generated when CDC is enabled for that table:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ... (
    [__$start_lsn] ASC,
    [__$command_id] ASC,
    [__$seqval] ASC,
    [__$operation] ASC
)
```

The non-clustered index that includes the source table's primary key is the same way.

Caveats with `__$command_id`:

- [Some versions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/cdc-functionality-may-break-after-upgrading-to-the-latest-cu-for-sql-server-2012-2014-and-2016/) of SQL Server don't order these correctly. [Fully patched](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3030352/fix-the-change-table-is-ordered-incorrectly-for-updated-rows-after-you) systems shouldn't have a problem, though.
- This column is not available in the output of the [generated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) functions, which the official documentation [says you should use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-capture-instance-ct-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions). These functions do a few things for you, most importantly querying `WITH (NOLOCK)` to avoid database contention, but most of my own code queries those _CT tables directly instead.